# iterate through a dataframe and return index label and column label in a tuple

Tags: python

I have generated a correlation matrix based on the pearson's correlation. Based on these information i want to do some regression analysis. This is how the dataframe looks like:

[image]

Currently I'm manually going through the correlation matrix and select specific index label and column label to generate a regplot. But I was thinking this is counterintuitive since I can iterate through the correlation matrix and select specific columns and index labels and use a for loop generate multiple regplots at the same time. So I was thinking I could do a list comprehension to append every index and every label in a list. However I have no Idea how i can iterate through each value in the dataframe. I was thinking I could use  `dataframe.iterrows()` however this doesn't really make sense since it returns an index and the entire row. I would love to hear some suggestions!

Comment: Can you edit the question and try to show a part of what it is you actually want coming out?  Do you want to, say, call some function with each pair of variables, like `do_something("a", "b")`, `do_something("a", "c")`, and so forth?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do it!

```
all_combinations = combinations(df.columns, 2)
all_comparisons = [(index, row) for index, row in all_combinations if df.corr().loc[index, row] > 0.5]
```